# How can I write the sum function in react native calculator construction?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> here, for example, I want to sum the numbers I entered. I want it to be similar to other functions

```js
  state={
number:'',
  };

harrik= (number) =>{
    this.setState({
      number: `${this.state.number}${number}`
    });
 };




setReset=() => {
  this.setState({
    number: this.state.numbervalue=""
  })
}

setNagative=() =>{
  let number = parseFloat(this.state.number) * -1;
  this.setState({
    number: number.toString()
  });

}
```

Comment: where's the numbers' array?

Comment: state={
    number:'',
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getSum=() =>{
  const { numbers } = this.state;
  const sum = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}, 0);
 this.setState({
    numbersSum: sum
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things about your syntax:

1. in harrik, you are appending the previous value of number with the new value as a **String**. if you want to turn it into a sum, do this:

```
harrik = (value) =>{// i renamed the 'number' argument to 'value' to avoid confusion
    this.setState({
      number: this.state.number + value
    });
 };
```

2. in setReset you are making two different mistakes, first you are trying to assign a value to this.state.number by putting an equal in front of it and second you are trying to pass the result to number. the code is more like this:

```
setReset=() => {
  this.setState({
    number: 0
  })
}
```

this will set the value of number to zero. if you don't want it to be zero, you can replace 0 with `null`.
3. in setNegative you can do this:

```
setNagative=() =>{
  this.setState({
    number: this.state.number*(-1)
  });
}
```

if you need these values to be string, you can stringify them when you want to show them using `.toString()` but for doing operations i highly suggest that you keep it in a number format to avoid problems.

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding.